# Getting Forbidden Error when clicking hyperlink from my UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, hyperlink, redirect

This is some strange issue. I have following hyperlink in my angularjs template:

```
Check the logs <a ng-href="{{task.myUrl}}" target="_blank"> Here </a>
```

When user clicks the hyperlink "Here" , it opens the new tab with correct link (say https://example.com/abc2322/logs). But it says "Forbidden". Even if I refresh the page it gives same error.

But surprisingly if I copy this link and open in new tab, it works well. Also If I will right click and choose to open in incognito window, it works well.

Can anyone please let me know what can be issue here.

Comment: That sounds like hot-linking has been disallowed on the server you're getting the page from (can only be opened directly - not from links).  I take it it's not your website you're opening?

Comment: Does it happen for the link https://google.com?

Comment: no..it works well with google.com

Comment: Is the URL a static page?

Comment: No URL is a dynamic page. (it updates logs in some intervals)

Comment: How you are calling this web service?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure its the hyperlink. When I click this, it opens a new tab with message Forbidden.